# Creating an array of arrays from elements

Tags: arrays, julia

I have a question regarding building a bunch of arrays off of a single array.

Suppose I have `myarr = [2,3]`. I want to build an array of arrays that contains elements that are at least half as big (going up to some limit I have defined maxSize as a single element, but leaves the others unchanged) and with steps defined (e.g. `stepsize=0.5`). For example suppose `maxsize = 5`, the first element in myarr is 2 and so I want to create:

```
[1,3]
[1.5,3]
[2,3] # Ideally I should exclude myarr...
[2,1.5]
[2,2]
[2,2.5]
[2,3]
```

Is there anyway to construct this?

Comment: It's unclear to me what you are trying to do. Could you show the entire output you are looking for? (Also, you open a parenthesis that you never close, so I'm not sure how to interpret the main sentence describing what you want.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want

```
julia> [(x = Float64.(myarr); x[idx] = v; x) for idx in 1:length(myarr) for v in myarr[idx]/2:stepsize:min(maxsize, myarr[idx]) if v ≠ myarr[idx]]
5-element Array{Array{Float64,1},1}:
 [1.0, 3.0]
 [1.5, 3.0]
 [2.0, 1.5]
 [2.0, 2.0]
 [2.0, 2.5]
```